# Not saving data of some fields

Tags: python, django

Hello I am trying to save a new registered user to database. Besides native User Model I have a Profile model with additional fields and here is my problem, after registrations fields named 'gender' and 'birthday' are not saved to database, but the user and profile is created with according fields.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_prof = models.ImageField(
        default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        default='male',)

    birthday = models.DateField(name='birthday', null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'


    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm,  ProfileGenderBirthdayForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        bg_form = ProfileGenderBirthdayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            if bg_form.is_valid():
                user.profile.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, f'{username} Your account has been created! You can now log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        bg_form = ProfileGenderBirthdayForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'bg_form': bg_form}

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

html

```
{% extends "indi/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
      {{ form | crispy }}
      {{ bg_form | crispy }}
       </fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="border-top pt-3">
    <small class="text-muted">
      Already Have An Account?
      <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can we see the html

Comment: I have just added the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never save the profile form. It should be:

```
if form.is_valid() and bg_form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    profile = bg_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
```

Comment: I have got such en error..IntegrityError at /register/
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id

Comment: You apparently have a post-save signal on User that automatically creates a Profile. You should remove that.